# Find a string in a document and delete everything after it

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, range, document

I want to find a string in a word document and delete everything after it.

What is the best way to do this without using the `Selection` object?

Comment: why don't you want to use the Selection object? Seems to be an aritrary constraint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a `Range` object instead. Straight outta the Word 2003 help:

> If you've gotten to the Find object
>   from the Range object, the selection
>   isn't changed when text matching the
>   find criteria is found, but the Range
>   object is redefined. The following
>   example locates the first occurrence
>   of the word "blue" in the active
>   document. If "blue" is found in the
>   document, myRange is redefined

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="blue", _
    Forward:=True
If myRange.Find.Found = True Then
```

Now use the `SetRange` method of that `Range` object to make the start of the range be the next character after the end of the string you searched for and make the end of the range be the end of the document:

```
myRange.SetRange (myRange.End + 1), ActiveDocument.Content.End
```

(TODO: You'll need to deal with the case when your string is the last thing in the document)

To delete the contents:

```
myRange.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub delete()

```
Dim findtext As String
findtext = "$_delete" 'Your word
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute
 
If (Selection.Find.Execute(findtext) = True) Then
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .text = ""
        End With
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    

    Selection.delete Count:='here the number of contents you want to delete
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).