# How to change sentence construction using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have over a hundred text files and I need to change the construction of several sentences using a specific format. I am not very familiar or experienced with Word VBA but I hope I could get some ideas to help me get started. I have below the original paragraph and its desired output. Basically I need to place the values (e.g. 40-120 parts) after each item (e.g. isoleucine) and enclose those with "(" and ")".

**Original:** An acid combination for increasing immunity, comprising the following raw materials by weight: 40-120 parts of isoleucine, 45-135 parts of leucine, 76.5-229.5 parts of lysine hydrochloride, 21.5-64.5 parts of methionine, 35-105 parts of phenylalanine, 40-120 parts of valine, 30-90 parts of threonine, 39-117 parts of arginine, 23-69 parts of histidine, 37.5-112.5 parts of glycine, 50-150 parts of aspartate, 900-2700 parts of dried mushroom, 750-2250 parts of medlar and 250-750 parts of licorice.

**Desired Output:** An acid combination for increasing immunity comprises (pts.wt.): isoleucine (40-120), leucine (45-135), lysine hydrochloride (76.5-229.5), methionine (21.5-64.5), phenylalanine (35-105), valine (40-120), threonine (30-90), arginine (39-117), histidine (23-69), glycine (37.5-112.5), aspartate (50-150), dried mushroom (900-2700), medlar (750-2250) and licorice (250-750).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the following sequence :

- Find the part you want to change (numbers seperated by `-` and parts) with the [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221467%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function (another [link](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=125085)) and a well-formed regexp (meant [wildcards](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm) for Word)
- Set the brackets at the beginning and at the end of the matched element (use the [range object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497624/vba-word-range-question))
- Delete the last word ("part") - or whatever you want to do
- Loop through every results to do the same (see an example of looping through find function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369177/find-italic-fonts-in-word-document-using-vba/))

Don't forget you can record macro if you are looking for some tips or specific objects (even if the code produced is less complete than the one produced by Excel vba).

Please don't hesitate to post some code if you want some more help,

Regards,

Max