# find italic fonts in word document using vba

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

With the `Find` function(`Ctrl+F`) I can search and select all words in Italicized font from a document.
How would this be done with vba?

I tried the macro recorder but the code I get there does not work.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
' Makro aufgezeichnet am 16.06.2011 von u0327336
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
End Sub
```

The goal would be to have all italic font words being selected/highlighted in the document.

thanks,
kay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add :

```
Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True
```

That could became :

```
With Selection.Find
   .Text = ""
   .FOnt.Italic = True
   'other search stuff
End with
```

**EDIT**: another try (not complete though)

```
Sub hilightItalic()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        ' to ensure that unwanted formats aren't included as criteria
        .ClearFormatting
        'You don't care what the text is
        .Text = ""
        'Find the italic text
        .Font.Italic = True
        'Delete the text found
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        'delete all italic text
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        '.HitHighlight "", vbYellow, vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

But yet, the replace does work well but highlight does not work if there is no text. Anyone has an idea ?

**EDIT 2**: Found a working solution, even if i did not manage to have hithighlight working though

```
Sub hilightItalic()
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With oRng.Find
        ' to ensure that unwanted formats aren't included as criteria
        .ClearFormatting
        'You don't care what the text is
        .Text = ""
        'Find the italic text
        .Font.Italic = True
        'Loop for each match and set a color
        While .Execute
            oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdDarkYellow
            oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Regards,

Max

Comment: I dont think thats going to work. You are changing the result of the find to have an italic font. Not to mention that as implemented, that find statement is not actually finding anything...

Comment: the last code does not work as highlight all text in the find/replace box does but it gives a workaround. i did not succeed in making the hithighlight method work, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The last effort actually works a treat in Word 2010.  I'm not sure why the report was that it didn't work.

Here it is changed to ASCIIfy italics, which is what I want for text-based newsgroups:

```
 Sub ASCIIfy()
    Dim myString As Word.Range
    Set myString = ActiveDocument.Content
    With myString.Find
        '// ensure unwanted formats aren't included as criteria
        .ClearFormatting
        '// we don't care what the text is
        .Text = ""
        '// find the italic text
        .Font.Italic = True
        '// loop for each match and surround with "_"
        While .Execute
            myString.Text = "_" & myString & "_"
            myString.Font.Italic = False
            myString.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True`.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

' The next line does the trick.
Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "YourText"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```

Hint for the next time: Record a macro, perform the actions you want to automate, and look what code is recorded. That's how I found this. :D

[edit]

I see that you tried recording it. Weird that that didn't work.. :-S

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the cells in the range that you want to check, and specifically check if it has its font italicized. AFAIK `.Italic` is not a "findable" option.

The following code is an example of iterating through the cells to find what you need.

```
Sub TestMe2()

Dim rng As Range

'// change as needed to the proper worksheet reference
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    '// replace the .Range statement with an appropriate range for your data
    For Each rng In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 100))

        If rng.Font.Italic = True Then
            '// uses the yellow highlight color, change to suit your needs
            rng.Interior.Color = 65535
        End If

    Next rng
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Hari, i am working on a working solution. Btw, i had understood that the Kay was looking for a MS WOrd solution. Trying to be back soon.

Comment: @JMax: I see the `MSWord` tag now... feeling a bit sheepish. Thanks for setting me straight...