# Find Text in an email and delete all text before this in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2013

I would like to find a string in an email, and delete all text before it. It is much the opposite of this:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub DeleteAfterText()

' Deletes all text after endStr.

Dim currMail As mailitem
Dim msgStr As String

Dim endStr As String
Dim endStrStart As Long
Dim endStrLen As Long

Set currMail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
endStr = "Text"
endStrLen = Len(endStr)

msgStr = currMail.HTMLBody
endStrStart = InStr(msgStr, endStr)

If endStrStart > 0 Then
    currMail.HTMLBody = Left(msgStr, endStrStart + endStrLen)
End If

End Sub
```

Example taken from this stack overflow page: [Find Text in an email and delete all text after this in Outlook 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052358/find-text-in-an-email-and-delete-all-text-after-this-in-outlook-2010)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key line would be something like this:

```
currMail.body = Right(msgStr, Len(msgStr) - (endStrStart - 1))
```

Adding a bit more to the original code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBeforeText_not_olFormatHTML()

Dim currMail As mailItem
Dim msgStr As String

Dim endStr As String
Dim endStrStart As Long
Dim endStrLen As Long

Set currMail = ActiveInspector.currentItem
endStr = "Text"
endStrLen = Len(endStr)

If currMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
    currMail.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
End If

msgStr = currMail.body
endStrStart = InStr(msgStr, endStr)

If endStrStart > 0 Then
    currMail.body = Right(msgStr, Len(msgStr) - (endStrStart - 1))
End If

End Sub
```