# Delete text that is after selection is found in Word2010 with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to delete a set of sentences (could be 1 or more) that occurs immediately after the selected text that has been found. I use Selection.Find to find the text, but I am unable to find anything that allows me to delete was it after the selection instead of deleting the selection itself.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = req
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
        End With

        'execute search
        Selection.Find.Execute

         If Selection.Find.Found Then
            'Found the tag, check for a duplicate
            Selection.Find.Execute
            If Selection.Find.Found Then
               'Found a duplicate
               err = True
               err_req = err_req & " " & req
            Else
                num_updated = num_updated + 1
                'Update the requirements text
                ' TODO: Delete the current requirements text
                Selection.InsertAfter req_text_list(index)
                'Set the requirement style
                Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Para"
                Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(STYLE_NAME_RQMT)
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            End If
        End If
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497624/find-a-string-in-a-document-and-delete-everything-after-it  It finds a string, then deletes everything after it.  You don't mention how you decide how many sentences to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of deleting the words, it is better and faster to replace the word with "". I have used it in the below code. Use it as per your requirement

```
Sub Wordsearchh()
Dim rWord As Range
Dim Search_Text As String
Dim Next_Word_Rang As Range
Set Next_Word_Rang = ActiveDocument.Range 


For Each rWord In ActiveDocument.Words
    Search_Text = rWord.Text 

    Next_Word_Rang.Start = rWord.End
    Next_Word_Rang.End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
        With Next_Word_Rang.Find 

            .Execute FindText:=Search_Text, Forward:=True

            If .Found = True Then
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
           End If
        End With
Next
End Sub
```